# how to make an excel vba run over several worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a from to to Information on Excel and what I want to do is to search the distances and time from Point a to Point b and from Point b to Point a. Then I want to insert the value which is smaller between this comparison.

I actually have a code working, but it can search only over one worksheet. I have the data of 4 worksheets and I Need to make sure that for each entry it searches over 4 worksheets. The code is below;

```
Sub CorrectTable()

    Sheet1.Columns(4).Cells.ClearContents

    For i = 1 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        Dim o_d, o, d As String

            o_d = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value

            o = getO(o_d)

            d = getD(o_d)

        If Not (o = "") And Not (d = "") Then

            Dim d_o As String

                d_0 = d & "." & o

            Dim od_time, od_dist As Double

                od_time = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value

                od_dist = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value

            For j = i + 1 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

                If Sheet1.Cells(j, 1).Value = d_0 Then

                    Dim do_time, do_dist As Double

                        do_time = Sheet1.Cells(j, 2).Value

                        do_dist = Sheet1.Cells(j, 3).Value

                    If od_time <= do_time Then

                        Sheet1.Cells(j, 4).Value = i

                    ElseIf do_time <= od_time Then

                        Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value = j

                    End If

                End If

            Next j

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

So how can I make this code searching through the 4 worksheets and find the corresponding entry?

Thank you

Comment: how about you do some reading on `for each ws in worksheets`

Answer (score 0):

Place within the j loop:

```
maxsheetlen=65000
If j > maxsheetlen Then
    Sheets(2).Cells(j-maxsheetlen, 4) = i
Else
    Sheets(1).Cells(j,4) = i
End if
    'do for "ElseIf do_time <= od_time Then" option
```